# JavaScript form validation message keeps triggering when typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

EDIT: I am using Symfony forms to create the form but not sure if that is relevant

I am validating a textarea element to check for only whitespace, and throwing an error if there are no characters. The check works and is triggered by the submit button. However, if the validation message triggers, it will keep appearing every time I type, even if it is not whitespace.

This is my JS file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//the submit button is #announcement_create_save
    $('#announcement_create_save').click(function () {
        var content = $('#announcement_create_content').val();
// The regex which checks if the field only has whitespace
        if (!(/.*\S+.*/.test(content))) {
            document.getElementById('announcement_create_content').setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field.');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('announcement_create_content').setCustomValidity("");
        }
    })
});
```

HTML

```
<form name="announcement_create" method="post">
                        <div class="announcement-card-body">
                            <label for="announcementText" class="content-label">Announcement (Supports Markdown)</label>
                            <textarea id="announcement_create_content" name="announcement_create[content]" required="required" class="form-control announcement-text" rows="5" name="content" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="card-footer border-0 bg-white pt-0">
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" id="announcement_create_save" name="announcement_create[save]" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fas fa-check"></span>  Post announcement </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: If you only check on submit then there's nothing to make the validation message go away. Are you saying, in fact, that if you type whitespace, click submit, then type more stuff, and click submit, it's still showing?

Comment: @DaveNewton once I click submit the initial time, and the message triggers, simply typing in the textarea will fire the message, without needing to hit the submit button

Comment: Can you show us what is happening by uploading your HTML too?

Comment: Once you've `setCustomValidity` the form isn't valid. You don't do anything to un-set it except click submit (and it shouldn't submit if it's invalid, so it might never run again, not sure). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity -- same thing I said the first time.

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves edited to add the html

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry not sure what you are meaning. Submitting the form when valid works perfectly fine. I am trying to only show the validation message when the submit button is pressed and the form is NOT valid. However, the message is popping up while I type in the textarea

Comment: Once you've set it to invalid you don't do anything to set it to valid. It's invalid until you indicate it's valid. You don't.

Comment: @NawedKhan I am pretty sure. Only I have worked with these specific DOM elements and I have written no javascript using keystroke triggers.

Comment: "it will keep appearing every time I type" you mean it stays and does not go away. How can it go away if you have not hit submit to recheck?

Comment: @NawedKhan How can I have it go away without having to submit again?

Comment: Validate on KeyUp of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

After validation is fired a popup notification of validation is displayed for a few seconds

[image]

Wait until this validation message is fired and after that try to enter the textarea.

Alert will not fire every time while typing it takes delay due to javascript load for few secounds.